# Dart observable list removed items

Tags: list, dart, observablecollection, dart-polymer

I just started to use observable list in dart. It notifies when the list is updated. When it's a removing case, it only gives me the index it removes from and how many items were removed. How am I supposed to know which items were removed since I only have indices and the 'updated' list (the items have already been removed from it.) I want to know if I miss something before I manually put extra code in it.

Thanks,
yi

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: say I have a list [obj0, obj1, obj2] and i do list.removeAt(0). Currently it gives me which index has been changed which is 0 and the "modified" array which is [obj1,obj2] so I have no way to get obj0 once I performed the remove action. My question is is there any way that I can get the obj0?

Answer (score 0):

The List `removeAt()` method returns the removed object.  So, you can simply assign the value of `removeAt()` to a variable, like this:

```dart
var list = [obj0, obj1, obj2];
var first = list.removeAt(0);
```